# Endoblar: hacer que dos ovejas críen a la vez un cordero

Tags: significado, definiciones, animales

No entiendo el significado de "hacer que dos ovejas críen a la vez un cordero", que es la definición de ["endoblar"](https://dle.rae.es/?id=FDIp4dg).
¿Significa que se críen dos ovejas y un cordero a la vez?

Comment: Significa que el cordero hace que dos ovejas críen a la vez.

Comment: Un hijo, dos madres. Así crece más rápido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acuerdo con la definición de [**endoblar**](https://dle.rae.es/?w=endoblar):

> 1. tr. Entre ganaderos, hacer que dos ovejas críen a la vez un cordero.

y la de **cordero endoblado** en el artículo [**cordero**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=AqtfRZT) del DLE:

> `cordero endoblado`
>
> 1. m. cordero que se cría mamando de dos ovejas.

significa que el cordero es criado (alimentado) a la vez por dos ovejas.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus aportaciones!